# An orientable 4-manifold with completely nontrivial 2-type

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, 4-manifolds, higher-homotopy-groups

I'm looking for a closed, *orientable* 4-manifold $M$ with completely nontrivial 2-type. By "completely nontrivial", I mean the following:

- The fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$ has to be nontrivial.
- The second homotopy group $\pi_2(M)$ has to be nontrivial.
- The action of $\pi_1(M)$ on $\pi_2(M)$ has to be nontrivial.

A nonorientable example would be $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times S^2$, thanks to Chris Schommer-Pries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any simply-connected oriented $4$-manifold $M$ and perform surgery on an embedded $S^0$ (i.e. take out two disks and glue together the remaining boundaries).

The universal cover of this can be explicitly described as $\mathbb{Z}$ copies of $M$ with those disks removed, glued together in sequence, with deck transformations acting by translation on summands.

So $\pi_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. $\pi_2$ is the same as $H_2$ of the universal cover, which is easily seen to be a sum of $\mathbb{Z}$ many copies of $H_2(M)$. $\pi_1$ acts by translation on summands.

So this construction gives an example, starting with any simply-connected $M$ with nontrivial $H_2$.

Comment: Isn't that just $M \# (S^1 \times S^3)$?

Comment: Ah, yes it is! So I guess the easiest example should be something like $(S^2\times S^2)\#(S^1\times S^3)$

Comment: So then it seems like this agrees sort of with [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93282/homotopy-groups-of-connected-sums)?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it is the right generalization. I guess that means almost any connected sum of $4$-manifolds will have nontrivial action of $\pi_1$ on $\pi_2$ (as soon as one manifold has nontrivial $\pi_1$ and the other has nontrivial $\pi_2$, Ryan's description tells you that the connected sum has a nontrivial action.)